# How to play YouTube video automatically in ngx-youtube-player module?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 7. And i installed `ngx-youtube-player`to play youtube video in component. But unfortunately it plays videos manually by default. But I want to play video when route or component will be loaded. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

I googled a lot to solve this but I can't

Comment: provide a stackblitz at least, we do not know what errors/issues .. u're facing :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-youtube-player?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I want to play video automatically

Comment: It's a third party package, not sure how it works, if you want to achieve same in html5 there is an attribute for autoplay,

<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Comment: But I need to use youtube api as well. I can embed video but how can use api with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after a lot of hard works.
I followed [ngx-youtube-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-youtube-player) official documentation. then I found out that was the version problem.